# Android on-screen keyboard auto popping up

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

One of my apps has an "opening screen" (basically a menu) that has an `EditText` followed by several `Button`s. The problem is that several of my users are reporting that when they open the app it's automatically popping up the on-screen keyboard without them even touching the `EditText`. As far as I can tell, all of these users are using the [HTC Hero](http://www.htc.com/www/product/hero/overview.html).

Is this a bug in 1.5? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: If it's a bug, it's probably in the Sprint Hero specifically.  Sprint has a buggy version of Android on the Heros they sell and they don't seem to be in any hurry of pushing out bugfixes for it.  There are tons of differences in behavior between the Sprint Heros and all other Android devices.  As far as I know the other versions of the Hero, such as those in Europe don't have these issues.

Comment: unfortunately the Hero's here in Europe do have major issues, they change depending on the build number but we have come across 3 - 4 major bugs.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You can use the following line of code in the activity's onCreate method to make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (2.2 MyTouch 3G). In my onCreate() method, I call setSoftInputMode(). The EditText still causes the keyboard to show :(

Comment: This worked for me. I'm running Android 2.3.4, and developing using <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

Comment: Or use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892615/how-to-remove-auto-focus-keyboard-popup-of-a-field-when-the-screen-shows-up/4454195#4454195)

Comment: So what's confusing me is that I have a login activity that already seems to be hiding the keyboard just fine. I've made a register activity now too but the keyboard is popping up by default. So how is the login one avoiding this? I can't find the setSoftInputMode in the login activity, or the windowSoftInputMode attribute in the activity.xml.

Comment: doesnt always work:   on some devices, SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN causes the error that an edit text that is not the last on in the activity cannot cause the soft keyboard to appear. using "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"" in the manifest also has the same effect.   the developer docs state that the soft keyboard will not appear automatically unless it is forced to, but that is just plain wrong.

Comment: This helped me solve the most annoying bug in my program where the keyboard kept popping up every time I entered the search service activity I had set up. . Do you know where you got this information from. I'm curious?

Answer (score 87):

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
              >
```

This works for Android 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0 - Editor Used to Compile (Eclipse 3.7)

Place the 'windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"' in your application's manifest XML file for EACH activity that you wish for the software keyboard to remain hidden in. This means the keyboard will not come up automatically and the user will have to 'click' on a text field to bring it up. I searched for almost an hour for something that worked so I thought I would share.

Comment: Best solution I've found so far. Focuses the field without opening the keyboard. Works on Nexus S with 4.1.2

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" is also helpful if you're using fragments and you don't want the keyboard to change the layout

Answer (score 6):

This code will work on all android versions:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

 //Automatic popping up keyboard on start Activity

     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

 or

 //avoid automatically appear android keyboard when activity start
     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
 }
```

Comment: Plus 1 for telling which pops up and which dosen't

Answer (score 6):

Add this in your **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

It works perfectly. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, how I can call the keyboard now? It will not appears when call `requestFocus()`.

Answer (score 6):

Add this in parent layout of the XML.

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

It ensures the focus isn't on the editText when the Activity starts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either this in the onCreate() method of the activity

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or paste this code in the Activity tags in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Comment: I think you mean "stateHidden" rather than "stateVisible".

Answer (score 2):

In that version of Android, when a view is inflated, the focus will be set to the first focusable control by default - and if there's no physical keyboard, the on-screen keyboard will pop up.

To fix this, explicitly set focus somewhere else. If focus is set to anything other than an EditText, the on-screen keyboard will not appear.

Have you tried testing this by running Android 1.5 in the emulator?

Comment: I have tried it in the emulator (and just did it again to make sure I wasn't crazy). It acts "right" (meaning no keyboard pop-up). Also, when I originally wrote this my G1 was running 1.5 and it didn't act this way (when they keyboard was "hidden").

Comment: I still bet it has something to do with the initial focus.  Maybe it's something specific to the HTC Hero, but I'd try setting the focus explicitly to something else and see if that fixes it for your users.

Comment: Is there any way to give "nothing" focus?

Comment: This doesn't work for me (2.2 MyTouch 3G).  In my onCreate() method, I explicitly call requestFocus() on a Button, which is the second widget in the view.  The EditText still causes the keyboard to show :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add the single line of code in **Android Mainfest.xml** under activity tag

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.sams.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
 </activity>
```

this may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically like

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in `<activity tag` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Include this where the imports are on top:

```
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Add this code on OnCreate part:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.ShowSoftInput(_enterPin.FindFocus(), 0);
```

*This is for Android.xamarin and FindFocus()-it searches for the view in hierarchy rooted at this view that currently has focus,as i have _enterPin.RequestFocus() before the above code thus it shows keyboard for _enterPin EditText *

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragments, you need to call hideKeyboard every time in onResume and onCreate if you want to hide the keyboard.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "SectionMyFragment onResume");
        hideKeyboard();
    }

private void hideKeyboard() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (inputMethodManager != null) {
            if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "hideSoftInputFromWindow 1");
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow((getActivity().getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```