# How to remove auto focus/keyboard popup of a field when the screen shows up?

Tags: android, keyboard, popup, android-softkeyboard

I have a screen where the first field is an EditText, and it gains the focus at startup, also popups the numeric input type, which is very annoying

How can I make sure that when the activity is started the focus is not gained, and/or the input panel is not raised?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or

set activity property in manifest file as below in the application tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: Setting the android:windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest.xml file can be ORed with other values. Mode typically implies single values but in this case, the value is a collection of flags.
Description of values:
`Formats: flag Values: adjustNothing, adjustPan, adjustResize, adjustUnspecified, stateAlwaysHidden, stateAlwaysVisible, stateHidden, stateUnchanged, stateUnspecified, stateVisible  Specify the default soft-input mode for the main window of this activity. A value besides "unspecified" here overrides any value in the theme.`

Answer (score 147):

go to your application manifest file, and write this line for that activity you want to disable auto keyboard pop-up.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I put it in activity_main.xml.  This worked perfect when I put it in onCreate().
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 23):

To programatically not have the keyboard displayed, but the default widget still recieve focus call:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
                             LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in `onResume()`

Answer (score 14):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

> call the above method inside **onCreate()**.It prevent **softKeyboard** to show unless user select **EditText** by `tapping or clicking.`

or simply add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in Activity tag in `Manifest.xml`

Answer (score 12):

This is usually a mess. The first thing I try is try to steal the focus with another view via . You also have to have the focusable and focusableInTouchMode.

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <requestFocus/>
</TextView>
```

Comment: This works. I feel this is a cleaner approach but it also depends how your conditions are. I am accepting this one.

Answer (score 5):

Have another view grab focus. By default, the first focusable View will get focus when a layout is inflated. You can request focus on a different View via XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some other view">

    <requestFocus />
</TextView>
```

This works for any View.

If you want to do it programmatically, you can use `view.requestFocus()`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to your Activity in manifest only hides the keyboard when you are launching the activity, or as Google says

> When the user affirmatively navigates forward to the activity, rather
> than backs into it because of leaving another activity

To hide the keyboard also when user presses the back button and moves back to your activity from some other activity, use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getWindow().getAttributes().softInputMode==WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED)
{
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not like other forums, if you want to change your answer, just click the `edit` link and make your changes. And please try to format your code by selecting your code and using the Code Sample button `{}` or pressing `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score -1):

have not tried this nor am i near my programming computer, but I would suspect programmatically sending focus to the parent view or something of that nature could do the trick - thats more likely a workaround than a solution, but again not able to test it just a thought

Comment: I've tried that but doesn't work. I called `.requestFocus();` on a button, and still the keyboard popups.

Comment: thoughts can be added as comments