# Keyboard shows up after starting Activity because of ScrollView

Tags: android, interface, android-activity, keyboard

If my EditBox is not in a ScrollView, it won't open the keyboard automatically (which is good!) However, now it is included in one, it does this annoying thing every time I start the Activity.
I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892615/how-to-remove-auto-focus-keyboard-popup-of-a-field-when-the-screen-shows-up), but it didn't work for me.

This is my main.xml: http://pastebin.com/qp3Nc8sf

Removing RequestFocus doesn't help either. How can I disable the keyboard on startup? Or is there even a better way of using scrollbars?

Thanks,
Force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer; I have to add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" to the activity in the manifest. This leaves the keyboard open while rotating as well. Nevertheless thanks for the answer Vinayak ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried adding this to your onCreate function of the activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Well, that would work, however it closes the Keyboard if I rotate my phone.