# How to disable keypad popup when on edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app the first view of all my screens is an EditText, so every time i go to a screen the onscreen keypad pops up. how can i disable this popingup and enable it when manually clicked on the EditText????

```
    eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed);

    eT.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(eT.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/feedPageLogo"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wic_logo_small" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goButton_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/go" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/goButton_feed"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feedPageLogo"
    android:hint="@string/search" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/feedPageLogo"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/feed"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonsLayout_feed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/feedButton_feed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/feed"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iWantButton_feed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/iwant"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton_feed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/share"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/profileButton_feed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/feedListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ButtonsLayout_feed"
    android:layout_below="@id/feedLabel"
    android:textSize="15dp" >
</ListView>
```

the third view (EditText) is where the focus is.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The best solution lies in the Project Manifest file *(AndroidManifest.xml)*, add the following attribute in the `activity` construct

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

---

**Example:**

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

**Description:**

- *The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.*
- *The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.*

**Introduced in:**

- *API Level 3.*

[Link to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

**Note:**
*Values set here (other than "stateUnspecified" and "adjustUnspecified") override values set in the theme.*

Comment: This approach fails if you have a mix of text fields in the activity, some which you want to have a keyboard for, others for which you do not. See my answer for how this can be achieved on a per-text field basis in such a scenario.

Comment: @slogan621please spare a moment in understanding the question here. You are on a different tangent!

Answer (score 85):

You have to create a view, above the EditText, that takes a 'fake' focus:

Something like :

```
<!-- Stop auto focussing the EditText -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

In this case, I used a LinearLayout to request the focus. Hope this helps.

This worked perfectly...thanks to Zaggo0

Comment: Adding a useless view is a sub-optimal solution compared with adding android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" to the Activity's manifest entry.

Comment: @ChrisHorner in both you need to specified for activity or layout... is the same annoying thing.. both works well for this solution.

Comment: Adding a useless view isn't a good idea as @ChrisHorner has said, better add an attribute into Manifest file as suggested by him or add this line of code into your activity

                        `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: @ChrisHorner: that line has no effect in a Material app on Android 6.

Comment: I have to agree with Housefly's answer. ChrisHorner's answer is for an activity, what if you have an alert dialog with some input and you don't want the keyboard showing? This is a great solution, just add a "space" above it with 0 dimensions.

Comment: In my case everytime I click the Snackbar's button the keyboard pops up. I tried everything in this, how can I solve it?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" did not work. But this fake focus layout of 0 width/height did work. Thanks.

Comment: Such a bad implementation of View hierarchy! I think such should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 45):

```
     edittext.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Now you can use any custom keyboard you like.

Comment: its available from API level 21

Comment: @JithuP.S, why it is working on Karbon titanium whos API level is 19 ??

Comment: This looks exactly like the method I need, but unfortunately it doesn't prevent the keyboard from showing. Any reason that could explain that?

Answer (score 23):

People have suggested many great solutions here, but I used this simple technique with my EditText (nothing in java and AnroidManifest.xml is required). Just set your focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false directly on EditText.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_pin"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:password="true"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

My intent here is to use this edit box in App lock activity where I am asking user to input the PIN and I want to show my custom PIN pad. Tested with minSdk=8 and maxSdk=23 on Android Studio 2.1

[image]

Comment: this made my life easy  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 20):

Add below code on your activity class.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Keyboard will pop-upped when user clicks on the EditText

Answer (score 10):

You can use following code for disabling OnScreen Keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: and i can enable it again by using EditText.onClick(im.unhideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);) or something like that??

Answer (score 8):

**Two Simple Solutions:**

***First Solution*** is added below line of code in manifest xml file.
In Manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml), add the following attribute in the activity construct

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

**Example:**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

**Second Solution** is adding below line of code in activity

```
//Block auto opening keyboard  
  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

We can use any one solution of above. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Declare the global variable for InputMethodManager:

```
 private InputMethodManager im ;
```

Under onCreate() define it:

```
 im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(youredittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Set the onClickListener to that edit text inside oncreate():

```
 youredittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        im.showSoftInput(youredittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
});
```

This will work.

Comment: all the code is in the question, the onscreen keypad is not showing up when i click on the edit text

Comment: Are you testing this using an emulator or a device. If you are trying it using an emulator then you will not get the softkeys. Test it using a device. It will work.

Comment: yeah i am using a device to test

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. If you could post your code, the method in which you have written then it could be of some help. Or else the above code is working absolutely fine in my device.

Comment: oh...but no problem it got solved though...in a complete different way...thank you anyways...check my answer...that might help you as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code, write it under `onCreate()`

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                   InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);         
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 4):

try it.......i solve this problem using code:-

```
EditText inputArea;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inputArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputArea);

//This line is you answer.Its unable your click ability in this Edit Text
//just write
inputArea.setInputType(0);
}
```

nothing u can input by default calculator on anything but u can set any string.

try it

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had the same problem and I just tackled with focusable in the XML file.

```
<EditText
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You probably are looking for security also. This will help in that also.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @A.B for good solution

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

this case if you will disable keyboard in edit text , just add **android:focusableInTouchMode="false"** in edittext tagline.

work for me in Android Studio 3.0.1 minsdk 16 , maxsdk26

Comment: Is this a comment to `A.B`s answer? Or is it an answer to the original question? If this is a comment to `A.B`s answer, then you should use the comment option provided by StackOverflow and delete this answer to the original question.

Comment: sorry if i didn't understand to answer the solved answer .  i say thank to A.B for a good answer to clear my problem.. if i wrong , i can delete that answer , sorry @DavidWalschots .

Answer (score 2):

Try With this:

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText); 
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To close, you can use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Try it like this in your code:

```
ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);  

ed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
        imm.showSoftInput(ed, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  
    }
});
```

Comment: it is working the same way as previously it was....are thr any changes i need to do in the layout??? for this EditText view??

Comment: okay, now it works after adding few layout attributes...                android:clickable="true"    
android:cursorVisible="false"    
android:focusable="false"   thank you

Comment: no.do one thing.write the hiding the keyboard code in edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener() method and try

Comment: this would be the solution IF you could specify exactly when to use calling hideSoftInput.  the keyboard automatically pops up AFTER onCreate and onResume

Answer (score 2):

Only thing you need to do is that add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to the EditText in xml and thats all.(If someone still needs to know how to do that with the easy way)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code in your `onCreate()` method-

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:focusable="true"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <requestFocus/>
      </TextView>

      <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xamarin
you can add this

```
Activity[(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden)]
```

thereafter you can add this line in OnCreate() method

```
youredittext.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
```

If the targeted device does not support the above code, you can use the code below in EditText click event

```
InputMethodManager Imm = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
Imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(youredittext.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following pattern to work well for me in code where I want to show a dialog to get the input (e.g., the string displayed in the text field is the result of selections made from a list of checkboxes in a dialog, rather than text entered via the keyboard).

1. Disable soft input focus on the edit field. I can't disable for the entire activity, as there are edit fields I do want the keyboard to be used for in the same layout.
2. Initial clicks in the text field yield a focus change, a repeated click yields a click event. So I override both (here I don't refactor the code out to illustrate both handlers do the same thing):

   ```
   tx = (TextView) m_activity.findViewById(R.id.allergymeds);
   if (tx != null) {
       tx.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
       tx.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
               if (hasFocus) {
                   MedicationsListDialogFragment mld = new MedicationsListDialogFragment();
                   mld.setPatientId(m_sess.getActivePatientId());
                   mld.show(getFragmentManager(), "Allergy Medications Dialog");
               }
           }
       });
       tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               MedicationsListDialogFragment mld = new MedicationsListDialogFragment();
               mld.setPatientId(m_sess.getActivePatientId());
               mld.show(getFragmentManager(), "Allergy Medications Dialog");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In a Android app I was building, I had three `EditText`s in a `LinearLayout` arranged horizontally. I had to prevent the soft keyboard from appearing when the fragment loaded. In addition to setting `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to true on the `LinearLayout`, I had to set `descendantFocusability` to `blocksDescendants`. In `onCreate`, I called `requestFocus` on the `LinearLayout`. This prevented the keyboard from appearing when the fragment is created.

Layout -

```
    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/text_selector_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="3"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
       android:background="@color/black">

       <!-- EditText widgets -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

In `onCreate` - `mTextSelectorContainer.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the easiest solution, set the following attribute to `true` on your parent layout

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

.......
......
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This to enable and disable EditText....

```
InputMethodManager imm;

imm = (InputMethodManager)
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (isETEnable == true) {

    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    ivWalllet.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_yes);
    etWalletAmount.setEnabled(true);
    etWalletAmount.requestFocus();
    isETEnable = false;
    } 
else {

    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY,0);
    ivWalllet.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_unchecked);
    etWalletAmount.setEnabled(false);
    isETEnable = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Users:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, 
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, 
        WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden)] //SoftInput.StateHidden - disables keyboard autopop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer,

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Note: only for API 11+

Answer (score 0):

```
private InputMethodManager imm;

...


editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        hideDefaultKeyboard(v);
        return true;
    }
});

private void hideDefaultKeyboard(View et) {
  getMethodManager().hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

private InputMethodManager getMethodManager() {
        if (this.imm == null) {
            this.imm = (InputMethodManager)  getContext().getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        }
  return this.imm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines of code when you want to hide keyboard on screen on any event. It worked for me.

```java
context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );

final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText())       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

for any textview at your activity (or create fake empty textfiew with android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
) and add for this textview next:
android:textIsSelectable="true"

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `<request focus/>` tag from the xml file.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on this and show an example. Please see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Just need to add property `android:focusable="false"` in particular `EditText` in the layout xml. Then you can write click listner for `EditText` without keypad popup.

Answer (score -1):

It issue can be sorted by using,
No need to set editText inputType to any values,
just add the below line,
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

Comment: Hey, thanks for writing up an answer! However, since there are already so many answers here, it might be even more helpful if you actually wrote this as a comment on the answer of Ranjith Kumar instead of making it its own answer. It might also be interesting to mention what the effect of leaving out the `inputType` would be. But it does look like this would be good to know if I went with that other answer, so even if you insist on keeping this around as its own answer, please consider leaving a comment there anyway.