# How to disable the dialpad soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am working on the Phone app in tablet mode.I want to disable the soft keypad wen we click on the edit text.Can any one please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for hide

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Use this for show

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest:

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 

            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```