# Numeric input for textarea in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I am writing a web interface for mobile devices. And I want to restrict input in the `textarea`: numbers 0-9, space, enter. I would like to see the default numeric keypad for `textarea`. But for `textarea` by default standard keyboard is showing. If I use virtual keyboard (simple buttons and javascript) standard keyboard still shows. How to disable the standard keyboard for `textarea` or set default numeric keypad?

Comment: If I get your question right then this pretty much solves it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext

Comment: @DevlshOne I'm developing a web interface for mobile browser

Comment: @Andy, As is the duplicated question I've deferred you to.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken you not right understood my question

Comment: add  android:inputType="number" to your TextArea

Answer (score 4):

You can use the global attribute `inputmode` in `textarea`. This will open the numeric keyboard in Android and iPhone. Other keyboard variations are available such as `tel` (phone pad), `email`, and `url`.

```
<textarea inputmode="numeric">
</textarea>
```

See [the MDN docs on `inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) for more.

Answer (score -1):

```
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: is it for html pages?

Comment: It is for Android HTML page serves, yes.

Comment: My application runs on a web server, on a mobile device I am using only a browser. How can I use your code?

Answer (score -1):

You must set the Input Type to "number". The number type is used for input fields that should contain a numeric value. You can also set restrictions on what numbers are accepted.

Example:
Define a numeric field (with restrictions):
Quantity (between 1 and 5):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Use the following attributes to specify restrictions:

- max - specifies the maximum value allowed
- min - specifies the minimum value allowed
- step - specifies the legal number intervals
- value - Specifies the default value

Comment: If you use a virtual keyboard you can use preventDefault() on the textarea to prevent opening the default keyboard

Comment: I try use code: 
$(textarea_id).insertAtCaret(txt);
event.preventDefault();
but standard keyboard is showing

Answer (score -1):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/launch_codes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enter_launch_codes"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/launch" />
```

use the input type number in order to see the default numeric keypad

Answer (score -2):

Use the `android:inputType` option.

In the xml layout file, you can define your textarea like this :

```
<EditText
    android:id=yourID
    android:inputType="phone" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Isn't that for an Android app and not a HTML page?

Comment: That's the way i use it in my android app.

Comment: And is your Android app loaded in an HTML page off the web?

Comment: No, it's just a basic android app, i didn't understood Andy's question well i think. He's talking about html textboxes.