# Android disable keyboard completely unless a button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am designing an android app that is primarily used with an external keyboard. There are a few edit texts that I dynamically set the focus on. The problem is that whenever the focus is set, the soft input keyboard pops up. I would like to know how to disable this. But, if a user presses a button, I want to display a popup box along with enabling the keyboard. Can this be done? Can you completely disable the popup keyboard, and then enable it if a user presses a button to open a popup menu? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sooo.. you want to disable the keyboard until someone presses the keyboard????

Comment: I want the soft keyboard to be disabled from edit texts unless a button is pressed.

Comment: Check these answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private EditText ed;
    private Button b;
    private InputMethodManager imm;
    private boolean hide = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(hide)
                {
                    hide = false;
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    hide = true;
                    imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);   
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in the manifest in the activity tag:

```
<activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Comment: I have tried the stateAlwaysHidden, but when I go to press on one of my edit text elements, the keyboard still pops up. I only want the keyboard to pop up when I press a button.

Comment: Then use android:enabled="false" in the <EditText /> if nothing it's suppose to happen when you press on it. And enable it after you press the button.