# How to disable android soft keyboard when working in cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I have cordova application which loading the html pages from web. Now these web pages have input fields, so when click on these input fields android default keyboard appear. I dont want to use this keyboard as already have  customize keyboard as popup in side application.
What i try: add following configuration inside my activity in androidManifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

But nothing can stop appearing this default keyboard. Can someone suggest me how to disable keyboard for my application only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line in Manifest.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext).

Comment: Sorry it is not working even with that.. here is a change in Manifest: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

Comment: it can be work if android application using EditText. I tried to remove focus on input fields of a webpage and its work but as i am browsing different webpage so i cant remove focus on input on each page so that i am looking something inside my android application.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way but works:

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }, 100);
    return true;
}
```