# EditText requestFocus method shows both soft keyboard and custom keyboard in android

Tags: android

I am using custom keyboard for some edittext fields. when I call requestFocus() in onCreate it also shows soft(default) keyboard. whereas I only need to show custom keyboard. If i hide soft keyboard programatically and try to enter field in edit text using custom keyboard than app crashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext ?

Comment: paste your crash log

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `setContentView()` set blow code.

```
Keypad.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: than i can call request focus ?

Comment: call request focus in the xml for the first editText field

Comment: what is attribute for this /

Comment: Through xml  <Edittext...> <requestFocus />
</EditText> , programmatically you can achieve this by edittext.requestFocus().