# Dynamically disable keypad popup in android studio for an EditText

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I have an *EditText* object input which i am dynamically creating. **I simply don't want the keypad to popup when i select the *EditText* object** to enter text because i have made different buttons and set *OnClickListner*-s for all of them which will do the inputs but when the keypad pops up it covers the screen and i want to disable it because i don't want anyone to enter text from the keypad. i only want them to enter values from the buttons i have created.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext

Comment: I have already seen this question but its not the answer i am looking for. I dont want the keypad to popup even when i select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with setting **android:inputType="none"** in your edittext or following this thread

[Disable keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext)

Comment: Only change. I had to do that dynamically.

Comment: et.setInputType(InputType.INPUT_NULL);

Answer (score 3):

You can disable showing the keyboard with this:

```
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

And you can show it again with:

```
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
```