# disable popout keyboard android-studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `EdiText` in my project developed on android studio .

```
android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

I need to find a way to disable the keyboard when I click on the edit text, meaning that when I click on the `EditText` the keyboard should not open .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable keypad popup when on edittext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611833/how-to-disable-keypad-popup-when-on-edittext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.Number);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just disable it.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
et.setEnabled(false);
```

OR

Add `android:inputType="none"` in your xml

Answer (score 2):

In your code you need to do it programmatically this way: declare a global variable for `InputMethodManager`:

```
 private InputMethodManager im ;
```

In **`onCreate()`** method define it:

```
im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(youredittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Set the **`onClickListener`** to that edit text inside **`onCreate()`**:

```
youredittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        im.showSoftInput(youredittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
});
```

This will work.

Answer (score 2):

here you go.

```
public static void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent user to edit text  then you may use `android:enabled="false"` property in edittext

Comment: i dont want he will be enable - i want he just cant open the keyboard ..

Comment: @hadadrefael okay have to did it or not?\

Comment: i use another way , your way disable all the edit text and i want only the keyboard

Comment: @hadadrefael okay