# How to stop soft keyboard from coming up automatically in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android on-screen keyboard auto popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496901/android-on-screen-keyboard-auto-popping-up)

I have made an android app in which there are two textfields and few buttuns. When I click on another textfield ,then android in-built soft keyboard comes up automatically but I have my own buttuns in the app so I don't require the soft keyboard.So, how can I Stop soft keyboard from coming up.

Answer (score 1):

below code can help you for hide your soft key board

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code in your Activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```