# How to prevent EditText KeyBoard from showing?

Tags: android, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an edittext and some buttons which write to the edittext. When a start my app, the system keyboard pops up. I want to avoid it, because I don't need that keyboard. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2498772/3071356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **disable the Keyboard** for an `EditText`, use:

```
EditText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: It works, I updated my code take a good look. I also tested it. Use EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL

Comment: The only quirk with this approach is that you will not be able to press in the EditText to select text, nor will you see a blinking cursor.

Comment: TYPE_NULL is not for this. Its for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NULL

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="ActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The keyboard still pops up when I click on the edittext.

Comment: What if you are using multiple fragments in your activity?  This would put a blanket setting on all of them...