# List view taking app out of fullscreen mode

Tags: android, listview, fullscreen

I haven't written any code yet except the code to put the app in full screen mode but as soon as I add a list view to the layout the app no longer loads in full screen mode and the soft keyboard also comes up. Below is all the code so far.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // launches app in full screen immersive mode
    int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);

}
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/sales_tax"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/dollar_sign"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/totalTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/salesTaxEditText"
        android:hint="@string/sales_tax_percentage"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/totalTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/totalTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/totalTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/percent_sign"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/item"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/number"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/per_item"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/of_items"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/per_item"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemListListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/clearListButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_button"
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete_button"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/clear_list_button"
    android:id="@+id/clearListButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of an `EditText` can make the soft keyboard pop up on start of an Android app. Assuming that what you're asking about is a way to stop the keyboard popping up, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496901/android-on-screen-keyboard-auto-popping-up) might be of relevance.

Maybe try adding the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your **AndroidManifest.xml** under your Activity, such as:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.sams.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
 </activity>
```

as was written in the answer by @Mohanraj in the link provided.