# Android: EditText inside Scrollview: block softkeyboard autoshow

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

When an Activity has an EditText inside a scrollview, the softkeyboard is shown automatically.

But the EditText is not the main feature of the Activity.

How to prevent the SoftKeyboard from showing automatically when the Activity is created?

Some things dont solve the problem:

- Adding code to hide the softkeyboard causes problems reshowing it:

  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
- or in the manifest: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android on-screen keyboard auto popping up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496901/android-on-screen-keyboard-auto-popping-up)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot it causes trouble reshowing the softkeyboard, i said this int he question edit but the editor just cut it out of the question.

Comment: @AnsonVanDoren, that question does not have an answer for this one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The correct way to block the softkeyboard from showing automatically is to prevent it from focusing on the EditText.

For each edittext in your layout:

```
onCreate()
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText.setFocusable(false);
```

In your xml layout file:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:onClick="enableFocusable"
```

Then in the java class, a method...

```
public void enableFocusable(View view) {
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to remove `EditText` focus.

1-add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to the activity tag in the manifest

or

2-use `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

or

3-use `edittext.clearFocus();`

or

4- set

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

for another view.

**Note:** `edittext.clearFocus();`may not work because it sets the focus back to another focusable view in the activity, so with one view it just reset focus-ability to the same view.

Comment: No it doesn't actually clearing focus just sets focus on another view and the editText will regain focus-ability when another onClick event is performed check out the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: the 1 and 2 solutions cause trouble reshowing the softkeyboard.

Comment: Do you need an answer or you want to give me an Introduction to Philosophy lecture.
the answer is above ethier you accept it because it is right or not and one more thing you need to remove your comments because its irrelevant and wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`edittext.clearFocus();`
or add 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your onCreate method...

```
  this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```